# AWS Proton templates with Cloudformation Dynamic References

Tags: amazon-web-services, jinja2, aws-cloudformation

In an AWS Proton template, we define a variable using Jinja's double curly brace syntax `"{{}}"`. Cloudformation seems to use the same syntax for [dynamic references](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html).

For example using Cloudformation to define a RDS instance with a password stored in Secrets Manager would look like:

```
MyDBInstance2:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
    AllocatedStorage: 20
    DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
    DBName: !Ref RDSDBName
    Engine: mysql
    MasterUsername:
      Fn::Join:
        - ""
        - - "{{resolve:secretsmanager:"
          - Ref: DBCredentialsSecret
          - ":SecretString:username::}}"
    MasterUserPassword:
      Fn::Join:
        - ""
        - - "{{resolve:secretsmanager:"
          - Ref: DBCredentialsSecret
          - ":SecretString:password::}}"
    MultiAZ: False
    PubliclyAccessible: False      
    StorageType: gp2
    DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref myDBSubnetGroup
    VPCSecurityGroups:
    - !Ref RDSSecurityGroup
    BackupRetentionPeriod: 0
    DBInstanceIdentifier: 'rotation-instance'
```

Is it possible to include a dynamic reference in a Proton template? How can I tell what is going wrong with my template?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution:

Jinja supports escaping using the "{% raw %}{% endraw %}" syntax ([documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#escaping))

Using that, I was able to construct the following valid template:

```
MyDBInstance2:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
    AllocatedStorage: 20
    DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
    DBName: !Ref RDSDBName
    Engine: mysql
      MasterUsername:
        Fn::Join:
          - ""
          - - "{% raw %}{{resolve:secretsmanager:{%endraw%}"
            - Ref: DBCredentialsSecretAFB45EA2
            - "{% raw %}:SecretString:username::}}{%endraw%}"
      MasterUserPassword:
        Fn::Join:
          - ""
          - - "{% raw %}{{resolve:secretsmanager:{%endraw%}"
            - Ref: DBCredentialsSecretAFB45EA2
            - "{% raw %}:SecretString:password::}}{%endraw%}"
    MultiAZ: False
    PubliclyAccessible: False      
    StorageType: gp2
    DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref myDBSubnetGroup
    VPCSecurityGroups:
    - !Ref RDSSecurityGroup
    BackupRetentionPeriod: 0
    DBInstanceIdentifier: 'rotation-instance'
```